# Android Studio Autovalue in java module and using in Android module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1, auto-value

Using Android Studio I have an Android Module, and a Java module.
In the Java module, I want to use AutoValue to generate immutable classes.

All seems to work fine (files are generated in the Java module) but I'm unable to access those files in the Android project. Any suggestions?

**app\build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':domain')
}
```

**domain\build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.6'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
    apt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
}
```

**domain/MyLocation.java**

```
import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;

@AutoValue
abstract class MyLocation {

    abstract String name();

    @AutoValue.Builder
    abstract static class Builder {
        abstract Builder name(String _name);
        abstract MyLocation build();
    }
}
```

When I build the domain module (the java module), I see that the 'AutoValue_MyLocation' file is generated here:

```
\domain\build\generated\source\apt\main\my\package\domain\AutoValue_MyLocation.java
```

However, I am not able to use the generated class anywhere in my Android module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, by looking at the generated class I saw that it was not public, hence I could not access it in my Android Module.

To fix it, simple make the @AutoValue class public, like so

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class MyLocation {
    //
}
```